# Begining java on arrays. trying to group duplicate amounts

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to go through a list of names with amounts.

One array has the name of the person , the other has the amount the person gave i.e. john, 55 sally 40 john 33 sarah 55.

My objective is to total the like names and print out the name of the person and the total amount that was given.

John gave twice so he should total 88.  But I am getting the total right but my program is printing the name twice. So john 88 is printing twice... I know its likely because I put it in the first for loop its iterating the entire length of the array.

But I am unsure how to solve this?

```
import java.util.*;

public class chapterfive {
    public static void main (String[]args) {
       Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
       String[]names = new String[4];
       int[] scores = new int[4];
       for (int i = 0; i<names.length; i++) {
           names[i] = in.next();
           scores[i] = in.nextInt();
       }
       int amount = 0;
       String firstname = "";

       for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
           for (int j=0; j < names.length; j++) {

               if (names[j].equals(names[i]))
                   amount += scores[j];
           }

       System.out.println(names[i] + "  " + amount);
       amount = 0;
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be using a Map to simplify things, rather than keeping track of two arrays. But heres a fix that may work (haven't tested it)

```
   String firstname = "";

   for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
       int amount = 0;
       boolean skip = false;

       for (int j=0; j < names.length; j++) {
          //need to skip because we have already processed it
          if(names[j].equals(names[i]) && i > j) {
              skip = true;
              break;
          } 
          else if (names[j].equals(names[i])) {
               amount += scores[j];
          }
       }
       if(!skip) {
         System.out.println(names[i] + "  " + amount);
       }
   }
```

Comment: Thank you!! ^^^^ this was exactly what I was looking for...Thank you everyone I really appreciate it.  I was really frustrated.. it was driving me crazy!

Answer (score 1):

You can see that they have a relationship like Name -> Score , so if you think more abstract this is a dictionary with Key (Name) and Value (Score) , so you can use another data-structure  like a `Map` or you can use an array and make a class Person , have the arrayOrderer and when you add a new person check if that person exist in the array..

Example :

```
Map <String , Integer> people = new HashMap<>();
     for (int i=0; i<lengthYouWant; i++)
           {
               String name=in.next();
               int score=in.nextInt();

               if(people.contains(name)){
                 score= people.get(name)+score;
               }
                people.put(name,score);
           }
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply ...that wouldnt work because the amount needs to be the total..
for example i have four entries: 

john
55
john
33
sarah
22
sally
44

It is printing:
john  88
john  88
sarah  22
sally  44  /

It should only print John 88 once

Comment: @LindsayBaird i don't understand, you say that john may be it's twice in the array?

Comment: +1, using a `HashMap` will remove the problem of parallel arrays. The two sets of data are directly related and should be treated as such.

Answer (score 0):

If you make an array or list of the Person class you can implement Comparable and add a method to help in sorting.

Answer (score 0):

Java is an object-oriented language, which means, among other things, that you can make your own data structures.  Using parallel arrays is error prone, and it separates data you want to keep together.  So, what do you need to organize this?

First is a way of storing a name and an amount.  Call it `Donation`.

```
class Donation {
    private final String name;
    private final int    amount;
    public Donation(String name, String amount) {
        this.name = name;
        this.amount = amount;
        // EXERCISE: Add error checking.
    }
    public String getName()   { return name;   }
    public int    getAmount() { return amount; }
    public String toString() {
        return "Name: " + name +", amount: " + amount;
    }
}
```

Notice that this class's variables are final; they can't be changed once set.  They are set in the constructor, and there are get methods and a toString method that replaces what you have in your `System.out.println` statement.

Next, you need a way of storing the data.  Don't use arrays.  `List`s are more flexible.

```
private static List<Donation> donations = new ArrayList<Donation>();

// and in main:

while (true) {
    String name = null;
    int amount = 0;
    if (in.hasNext()) {
        name = in.next();
    } else {
        break;
    }
    if (in.hasNextInt()) {
        amount = in.nextInt();
    } else {
        break;
    }
    donations.add(new Donation(name, amount));
}   See -- no 4s.
```

Next, you need to consolidate the repeated donations.  I mean, some people give to their church every Sunday. We'll use the appropriate structure, a `Map`.

```
// Also in main:
Map<String, Integer> totals = new HashMap<>();
for(Donation d: donations) {
    String name = d.getName();
    int amount = d.getAmount();
    if (!totals.containsKey(name)) {
        totals.put(name, 0);
    }
    int currentDonation = totals.get(name);
    totals.put(name, currentDonation + amount);
}
```

And then finally, you iterate through the map and print each entry.

```
for ( Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry: totals.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ": " + entry.getValue());
}
```

And now, another exercise and strategy: stop doing everything in `main`.  Give your `ChapterFive` class instance variables and methods.  Then, write tests for these.  Try to find improvements to what I suggested.  Then, see if there are libraries that can help you.

Comment: why a list if you use a map?

Comment: True.  I guess I used a `List<Donation>` just to suggest to the poster that related data should be stored together.